# call a method inside another method in the same class

Tags: c#, matrix, static-methods

I'm working with C# and I'm trying to multiply a scalar by a matrix and return the results. The problem I have is the arguments can be passed in two ways. They can either come in scalar then the matrix, or the matrix then the scalar, so I need to set up two methods to handle them. I know I can simply duplicate the code in the second method, but as I understand it, a method call is a slicker way to do it since both methods use the same code. I just need some help on what that call would look like. My code is shown below.

```
public static Matrix operator*(int scalar, Matrix matrix)
{     
    uint row,col;
    Matrix matrixProd;

    matrixProd = new Matrix(matrix.Rows,matrix.Cols);
    for (row=1; row<=matrixProd.Rows; row++)
        for (col=1; col<=matrixProd.Cols; col++)
            matrixProd.TwoDArray[row,col] = matrix.TwoDArray[row,col] * scalar;
    return matrixProd;
}

public static Matrix operator*(Matrix matrix, int scalar)
{
    //I have no idea on what to put here to call the previous method.//
}
```

Comment: have you tried return scalar * matrix; ?

Comment: I had not. That works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can just reverse the order of the operands like this:

```
public static Matrix operator*(Matrix matrix, int scalar)
{
    return scalar * matrix;
}
```